# how does the dotnet WebApi takes location of near by users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, geolocation, logic

Im looking for some help to build a genuine logic to search near by delivery guys, So pls bear the explanation with me without voting down.

Im developing a WebApis(dotnet framework with C# & SQL) for food delivery app that are supoosed to be integrated with flutter mobile app. 
Now, when the order gets submitted, it should be assigned to nearest delivery guy.
I know the way to calculate distance but How would I get the locations of the delivery guys around certain distance?

**Is it a task of mobile end to provide me the list of (latitude and longitude) of delivery guys of certain distance?**
**If yes,What would be the API logic when receiving that list from webapi**

**Is there any other way to do it?**

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

well, we can only look at this from a high level.

you have:

- an API
- a mobile APP
- users who place orders
- delivery people who fulfill these orders

you want to assign orders to closest delivery guys.

First of all, "closest" doesn't mean much. Let's explore this a bit.
close to what ? the food outlet? the client? both? shortest distance between them?

Unclear, but this is something to bear in mind.

If you want to have the location of a delivery person, then you need to have some way of tracking their journey. 
Maybe they can have the app running in the background ( for the duration of their work hours ) and send their location once every minute to the API, like a location beacon.

This way, when an order is placed, the API can look at that data and somehow decide which one to assign it to.

This is one of way of doing this, I am sure there are other solutions as well.

Comment: Yes, the closest to the store. (im clear about this).
Thanks for the solution. just couple of question though

1) yes, the app will be running in delivery guyz phone and their location would be shared, how often should app look for those locations?
2)Do I need a service that runs 24hours and look for the locations? or there should be some other way?